# Executing MSBuild via C# using `Process.Start` fails with error but works if I try manually in the command line

Tags: c#, .net, shell, command-line, msbuild

I'm building a C# Program that manipulates existing projects and then tries to compile them.

My program is currently being built using `net6.0`.

I've located the SDKs (new dotnet.exe and old MSBuild.exe) on my machine. If I use dotnet.exe, it works fine and I've had no issues.

However, projects in the old non-sdk style can't be built using dotnet, so I'm trying to fall back to MSBuild.exe

Now I'm executing it using Process.Start (I've used CliWrap for ease of use, but also tried with the standard `Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo)` and had the same results) to start MSBuild.exe and pass it the project and some arguments. This looks like this:

```cs
        var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = Path.Combine(MSBuildDirectory, "MSBuild.exe"),
            WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(projectToBuild),
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            Arguments = $"\"{Path.GetFileName(projectToBuild)}\" /restore -t:build /p:Configuration=Release",
        };

        var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

This basically generates this command:

```
C:\Users\me\repo > "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "MyProject.csproj" /restore -t:build /p:Configuration=Release
```

This successfully starts building but then starts failing with some tasks, but the interesting thing is it's using the new .NET Core SDKs? Why and how is that happening when I'm passing it the old style `MSBuild.exe`?

The error I'm getting is this:

```
      Build Error: Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.2.1+52cd2da31 for .NET Framework
      Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

      Build started 04/08/2022 14:32:26.
      Project "C:\Users\me\repo\MyProject.csproj" on node 1 (build target(s)).
      Project "C:\Users\me\repo\MyProject.csproj" (1) is building "C:\Users\me\repo\DependentProject.csproj" (2) on node 1 (GetTargetFrameworks target(s)).
      C:\Users\me\repo\DependentProject.csproj : error MSB4244: The SDK resolver assembly "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.302\Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver.dll" could not be loaded. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver, Version=6.2.1.7, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
      Done Building Project "C:\Users\me\repo\DependentProject.csproj" (GetTargetFrameworks target(s)) -- FAILED.
      Done Building Project "C:\Users\me\repo\MyProject.csproj" (build target(s)) -- FAILED.

      Build FAILED.

      "C:\Users\me\repo\MyProject.csproj" (build target) (1) ->
      "C:\Users\me\repo\DependentProject.csproj" (GetTargetFrameworks target) (2) ->
        C:\Users\me\repo\DependentProject.csproj : error MSB4244: The SDK resolver assembly "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.302\Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver.dll" could not be loaded. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver, Version=6.2.1.7, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

          0 Warning(s)
          1 Error(s)

      Time Elapsed 00:00:00.15
```

However, if I take that generated command above, set the same working directory and run it manually in a new command prompt window, then it works.

Why and what is happening?

I thought Process.Start would spawn a new process, so whether I did that manually, or my program did it, they'd behave the same?

I've tried both 32 Bit and 64 Bit MSBuild.exe's and both give identical results. Both giving an error containing a path to thet .NET 6 SDK folder.

It's as if launching Process.Start from within .NET Core keeps some sort of .NET Core context?

Can someone help here?

Thanks

Comment: "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format" is a [BadImageFormatException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.badimageformatexception?view=net-6.0) and usually indicates that you are attempting to load a 64-bit assembly from a 32-bit application or vice-versa. I'd start looking there.

Comment: There will be 32 bit and 64 bit versions of MSBuild installed. [MSBuild and 64-bit Visual Studio 2022](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/msbuild-and-64-bit-visual-studio-2022/)

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: you can also dynamically compile C# code at runtime, [see here](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2022/Jun/07/Runtime-CSharp-Code-Compilation-Revisited-for-Roslyn) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/csharp/language-compilers/compile-code-using-compiler)

Comment: @mu88 I tried that but it wasn't working either. 
Was talking about missing assemblies. I tried using both Build.Runtime and Build.Locator. I think it's because my app is running on dotnet core, so only picks up the new sdks. I can switch to framework, but then it will switch the other way. That's why I'm trying via command line, as then it's a new process and theoretically the runtime of my app won't affect it.

Comment: @JonathanDodds I've now tried with both 32 and 64 MSBuild.exe's and gotten identical build failures. I feel like Process.Start in net6.0 is passing on some NET Core context or something somehow?

This error is basically saying it's looking in the net core SDK folder?


`task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.302\NuGet.Build.Tasks.dll`

But from the first line of the build you can see it's targeting .NET Framework


`Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.2.1+52cd2da31 for .NET Framework`

Comment: @MikeHofer see comment above (couldn't tag two people)

Answer (score 0):

I found it out via Microsoft Build Structured Logging. The difference was in the environment variables. My .NET Core program was passing on some Environment variables when spawning the new process. These were locations for the SDK - The one I didn't want it to use. I've set these to null and it's working now!

```
["MsBuildExtensionPath"] = null,
["MsBuildSDKsPath"] = null,
["MSBUILD_EXE_PATH"] = null
```